# spring security на все запросы ответ forbidden 403

Tags: java, spring-security

Всем привет.
На все запросы отвечает ошибкой 403.
Код настройки.

```
package ru.starry_sky;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import ru.starry_sky.security.jwt.JwtConfigurer;
import ru.starry_sky.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    private final static String ADMIN_ENDPOINT = "/starry_sky/admin/**";

    private final static String USER_ENDPOINT = "/starry_sky/users/**";

    private final static String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/starry_sky/login/**";


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(ADMIN_ENDPOINT).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(USER_ENDPOINT).hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }

}
```

ссылка на проект https://github.com/SoaQa/social-web/tree/starry_sky

Comment: вряд ли кто-то будет читать твой код)

Answer (score 0):

Изза того что я деплоил в томкат, у меня урлы начинались не с /starry_sky/, а сразу типо /login. А /starry_sky/ добавляет томкат -_-, потому что так называется варник.